# Custom EditText

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Is there any library or a means to implement this custom `editText`?[image]

This is what was achieved by wrapping a custom layout around the `editText` which is inside a `textInputLayout`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:minWidth="400dp">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/hint_title_required"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```